use of meta::forest() for plotting data
I would like to draw my data with meta::forest() of R but my dataset is not from a meta-anaylsis and I do not want to use ggplot2 and dplyr
The data to be drawn are: study_ID, risk ratio, lb.conf.int, ub.conf.int
Unfortunately, all tutorials and training materials present forest() in the context of meta-analysis or present forestplot() function from the library(forestplot). My actual aim is to generate forest plot in the design of the meta::forest() funtion
Many thanks

By the sounds of things, your data is in this format:
data
#>   study_ID risk ratio lb.conf.int ub.conf.int
#> 1        A       2.70        1.71        4.31
#> 2        B       2.33        1.49        3.66
#> 3        C       0.64        0.42        0.97
#> 4        D       0.37        0.23        0.59
#> 5        E       1.70        1.11        2.61
#> 6        F       3.76        2.28        6.27
#> 7        G       6.14        3.40       11.28
#> 8        H       1.86        1.21        2.86
#> 9        I       0.30        0.18        0.49

It's not clear why you want to use meta::forest here, or why you want to avoid ggplot, but you could draw a forest-type plot in base R without any packages:
plot(data$`risk ratio`, seq_along(data$study_ID), yaxt = "n", ylab = "Study ID",
     xlab = "Risk ratio", xlim = c(0, max(data$ub.conf.int)), type = "n")

segments(x0 = data$lb.conf.int, y0 = seq(nrow(data)), 
         x1 = data$ub.conf.int)

axis(2, seq(nrow(data)), data$study_ID)

points(data$`risk ratio`, seq_along(data$study_ID), pch = 15, col = "gray50",
       cex = 2)

abline(v = 1, lty = 2)


It's not clear if you want to avoid ggplot for any specific reason rather than unfamiliarity, but the code would be even easier
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(`risk ratio`, study_ID)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = lb.conf.int, xend = ub.conf.int)) +
  geom_point(shape = 15, color = "gray50", size = 6) +
  theme_classic(16) +
  labs(x = "Risk ratio", y = "Study ID") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = 2)



Reproducible data
data <- data.frame(
  study_ID     = LETTERS[1:9],
  `risk ratio` = c(2.7, 2.33, 0.64, 0.37, 1.7, 3.76, 6.14, 1.86, 0.3), 
  lb.conf.int  = c(1.71, 1.49, 0.42,  0.23, 1.11, 2.28, 3.4, 1.21, 0.18), 
  ub.conf.int  = c(4.31, 3.66, 0.97, 0.59, 2.61, 6.27, 11.28, 2.86, 0.49),
  check.names = FALSE)

